# Appending one row at a time from Dataframe to Google Sheet with Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets-api

I have this code for writing data to google sheets with Python. Is it possible to append one row at a time, instead of inserting the entire data frame at once?

```
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=os.environ['GOOGLE_SHEET_ID'],
                            range=range,
                            valueRenderOption='FORMATTED_VALUE').execute()

new_row = df.applymap(str).values.tolist()
result = sheet.values().append(
        spreadsheetId=os.environ['GOOGLE_SHEET_ID'],
        range=range,
        valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
        body=dict(
            majorDimension='ROWS',
            values=new_row)
    ).execute()
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `append one row at a time, instead of inserting the entire data frame at once`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: please include the library imports in your code

Comment: Please provide a detailed step-by-step process on how you would like to **append one row at a time** to help the community understand your goal better. Also, kindly provide a code that can be easily reproduced. See [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)